# Battery life problem in Linux on Asus notebook

Tags: power-management, asus, battery

I have  a new ASUS notebook core i7 6500U 8GB RAM.

When I'm running windows 10, the battery lasts more than 6 hours at least .

But when I'm running Linux it does not last more than 3 hours!!

I tested Ubuntu, Mint  and Fedora with different desktop environments; Xfce, lxde, GNOME shell, Unity, MATE...

I use powertop and tried tlp, without good results. I tried updating the system...

What else can I try?

Comment: Do you have a nvidia GPU in your laptop? - Have you installed TLP correctly with the right drivers meant for non-thinkpad laptops? - Which version of Ubuntu are you running? (16.04/16.10 etc) - Open up a terminal and type `top` and see what is eating your CPU. Please tell me how it goes :)

Comment: Please dit your question and post hardware specs (Asus notebook model, graphics, etc.) the best you can. Please keep in mind AskUbuntu supports Ubuntu and official derivatives only (Mint and Fedora are off-topic). With that in mind please choose one and install it for troubleshooting if you want help (16.10 or 16.04.1 are better for newer hardware). Do not install TLP just yet. I suspect you have an hybrid graphics system and you're using the integrated one with Windows and the discrete one with Ubuntu but we'll see after you provide useful information.

Comment: so sorry s3gm3ntationfault , but can you tell me what is ' non-thinkpad laptops ' , I don't know what is :(

Comment: okay ,  CelticWarrior.. I'll install Ubuntu 16.04 and tell you

Comment: some body told me that asus is not linux friendly,  is it ??